# WinRM service killed by remote script

Tags: powershell

We have a situation where a PowerShell script will kill the WinRM service on a remote server sporadically. Here is the script:

```
    $results = Invoke-Command -computername $hostname -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list WP" }

    $query = 'Select IDPROCESS,workingsetprivate,name from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process WHERE name LIKE "w3wp%"'

    $Pools = Get-WmiObject -computername $hostname -query $query

    foreach ($result in $results)
    {
        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $result -match '\d+' | Out-Null
        $AppPoolID = $Matches[0]

        $result -match '(?<=:)\S*(?=\))' | Out-Null
        $AppPoolName = $Matches[0]

        $Memory = $Pools | where IDPROCESS -eq $AppPoolID | Select -ExpandProperty workingsetprivate

        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $AppPoolID
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $AppPoolName
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Memory -Value $Memory

        Write-Host "$AppPoolName=$Memory"
    }
```

I've never seen a situation where WinRM is killed by a remote script.  The script runs every six minutes and is successfully 99.9% of the time but occasionally fails.

Here is the error from the event log on the target machine:

> Faulting application name: svchost.exe_WinRM, version: 6.1.7600.16385,
>   time stamp: 0x4a5bc3c1 Faulting module name: wsmsvc.dll, version:
>   6.3.9600.16406, time stamp: 0x5244e817 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0000000000120da9 Faulting process id: 0x9fb0 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d32aba968aefb7 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe Faulting module path:
>   c:\windows\system32\wsmsvc.dll Report Id:
>   4c9bd468-96fd-11e7-bbb4-005056ba0048

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the requests overlapping in time?  Every 6 minutes is a little unusual.

Comment: No I don't believe so.